# Dragging a JPanel using MouseMotionListener

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, drag, mousemotionlistener

I'm making a program where the user will drag a card across a table using the mouse. The Card is a `JPanel` and so is Table. Table has a `null` layout. In the Card class, I have this:

```
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
{
    if (this.getWhere() == 1) // makes sure the card is on the table
    {

        Table.table.moveCard(this, e.getX(), e.getY());
    }
}
```

Then in the Table class:

```
public void moveCard(Card card, int x, int y)
{
    card.setLocation(x, y);
}
```

When I drag the card, it will jump back and forth from where the mouse is and a point near the top left corner of the panel.

Any help?

Comment: Please post code we can compile, test and run, a [mcve]. Note that this is not your entire program, but rather a small new program that demonstrates your problem directly for us.

Comment: You will also need a MouseLIstener to do this correctly (a MouseAdapater would serve both purposes), since you need to store the first press location, both on screen and in the container, on mousePressed.

Comment: [similar questions that you should check out](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+dragging+jpanel+swing)